# Updating GUI controls from C# Class Library...?

Tags: c#, user-interface, class-library

Is there some wayaround to update Form's control from Class Library

I have a classlibrary as a seprate project and GUI (Form) as a separate project in same solution. And have aded reference of Class Libaray to my GUI project from where I access its functionality.

Now I want that when ever any particualr event happen in ClassLibrary (new data is aded from database or some exception caught)I write this to my LogFile but also WANT TO DISPLAY ON LABEL on Form.. , how can I acheive this thing

Any sugestions

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Can you update UI controls from a library? Obviously yes, if you pass the references. It's just a bad idea. Although, displaying log messages is a *completely* different question. What log library are you using? Why not just display the log file? Did you check for a GUI log appender? There may be one already available

Answer (score 0):

If "new data is aded from database or some exception caught", then you should raising an event and your GUI should listen to it, and do something with it, like actualize dataGridView or textBox....

Answer (score -1):

```
    var label = new Label();
    label.Text = "New Database Changes";
    this.Controls.Add(label);
```

Comment: How is this related to the question? Why is the assumption mande that the library is a UI control itself?

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.